# Windows PATH variable

Tags: windows, variables, path

My program needs .bat file to run because the .bat file is changing some language settings, so .bat file looks like:

```
set lang=en 
start ap.exe
```

It is working great but when I made installer for my `app` and pointed .bat file as main file, it creates a shortcut on the desktop to that .bat file. So far everything is great but when I launch that shortcut it cannot open app.exe because it can't find it on desktop.

So my question is: How can I get path to folder of .bat file so I could set proper start command? Something like:

> set lang=en
>
> S=getpath();
>
> start S/app.exe

It is just pseudocode but I think you get point.

Answer (score 3):

You can write `%~dp0` to get the directory containing the batch file.

Therefore, you can write

```
"%~dp0app.exe"
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Now it shows that "C:/Program" is wrong path which is truth because program is placed in C:/Program Files/App/App.bat  I think it does not like spaces in name?

Comment: Now it looks like: set lang=en
start "%~dp0App.exe"  And no error but it also does not launch exe file

Comment: Path from which I ran .bat. If I run from deskopt I get path to deskopt but if I run from app directory I get path to directory

Comment: Also name of console windows is the same as full path to .exe file including name of .exe file. Any fix to make it work?

Comment: +1, %~dp0 is a great tip, almost forgot about it's existence.